# Cannot build VS Code from sources - Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I cloned Visual Studio Code sources and followed the instructions for contributors from the link - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute but When I run yarn I'm getting the following error:

```html
error C:\_LAB_\vscode\node_modules\native-keymap: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: C:\_LAB_\vscode\node_modules\native-keymap
Output:
C:\_LAB_\vscode\node_modules\native-keymap>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\_LAB_\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-keymap\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Maga\\.node-gyp\\iojs-1.7.12\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Maga\\.node-gyp\\iojs-1.7.12',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Maga\\.node-gyp\\iojs-1.7.12\\<(target_arch)\\iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\_LAB_\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-keymap',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\_LAB_\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-keymap\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn msbuild
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
C:\_LAB_\vscode\node_modules\native-keymap\build\keymapping.vcxproj : error MSB4057: Target element "Build" does not exist in project.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\_LAB_\vscode\node_modules\native-keymap
```

I tried to rebuild the native-keymap project in VS2017 but then I got the similar message for two other node_modules and eventually again from native-keymap.

My PC environment:
Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Community.
Python: 2.7.14
Node: 8.11.1
npm: 5.6.0
yarn: 1.6.0

Comment: What version of `node-gyp` are you using?

Comment: Try deleting the `node-gyp` node_modules folder and running `npm install node-gyp`

Comment: node-gyp version is 3.6.2. Deleting and reinstalling didn't help. I even tried to reinstall node and all npm modules.

Comment: Node-gyp is a pain, normally those issues happen when some prerequired software for a compiling or pipeline step is missing. On Windows this is especially painfull to do i can recommand you to install https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools in order to setup and configure the enviroment for node-gyp on windows.

Comment: Unfortunately installing these windows-build-tools didn't change anything. The error still persists.